# ActiveWorkbook in NPOI

Tags: c#, excel, npoi

I want to edit the current active Excel-Worksheet in NPOI. 
The Codesample below Shows what I want to do. Problem is I would need it in NPOI and so I am asking whether any of you can help me as I can't find anything.

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application excel = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application)System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetActiveObject("Excel.Application");

Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Workbook wb = excel.ActiveWorkbook;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NPOI is not a wrapper around Office, it implements it's own access to the files. As such, it cannot be used to get the "Active" instance of Excel. It never directly interops with Excel in the first place. That's one of the features that makes it a powerful library, it doesn't depend on Office being installed and can therefore run on a server in an unattended way.

In case you want to interact directly with Excel, you need to use the [Microsoft Primary Interop Assemblies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/15s06t57.aspx), which will work just fine with the statements you referenced in your Question.

Comment: Thanks for helping, I just hoped I could do it without this tool.